# Gradlew war creation not including env variables

Tags: intellij-idea, environment-variables, war, gradlew, ktor

I am developing a backend application in Kotlin with Ktor and using Intellij. When deploying it, I use ./gradlew war to create a war file.

Until now, this worked perfectly until we moved some secret keys and passwords in the environment variables to stop exposing them in the code. Now, when creating the war file, the different options from environment variables seem not to be included.

For example, there is a file path defined in the environment variables, which is different when running on the local machine than when running on the deploy server. Every time we do the deploy, the correct path is not taken from the env vars, it uses the path from the local machine instead.

Any ideas on this? Should I specify something in order to make this work?

I tried hardcoding the path in the code, as it was before, and it works. So I deduced that the path taken from env variables is not correct